# Microsoft Office applications COM interface

Tags: c, com, ms-office

I previously asked this question: [Create COM object using plain C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33033111/create-com-object-using-plain-c)

While doing research about my previous question, the first solution I found was to use generic IDispatch interface and use Invoke to access Internet Explorer objects. Later I discovered that native C interface to Internet Explorer can be found in Windows SDK in exdisp.h header. Using this header was much cleaner solution to my problem.

However, I can't seem to find similiar header files for Microsoft Office applications. I am especially interested in Excel.

Is there a similiar header file that I can access freely? This header should expose Microsoft excel COM interface.

Answer (score 0):

there are tools that can import typelib and create from it idl file and c header file, these typelibs can be in a single file which have *.tlb extention or embeded as resouce in exe|dll|ocx file.

the best tool is oleview of microsoft included with any SDK. a good tutorial here from Codeproject:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3699/Importing-Type-Libraries

but i want to suggest better this addin source for pellesc:
http://www.johnfindlay.plus.com/pellesc/addin/RegTypeLib_WS.zip
a very good example to start

Comment: I have a follow up question if you are interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33065999/syntax-error-while-converting-idl-to-c-header

Comment: was the answer helpful?